# How to encrypt text into a image using python

Tags: python, steganography

I was wondering how can someone use python to encrypt text into an image.

Comment: Could you please clarify "to encrypt text into an image"? Did you happen to mean "hide text in an image"? Encryption requires a separate secret key to guarantee the text remains safe.

Comment: well yes! I meant hide a message into an image. Because I guess it would be simpler to just encrypt the message first and then hide it into the image

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335220/embed-text-into-png

Answer (score 7):

Google search for "python steganography" and you find some stuff.

Here's a Python library module: [stepic](http://domnit.org/stepic/doc/)

Comment: Don't use lossy compression when you save the image